# PHP unlink can't delete file while I can unlink this file in Linux shell

Tags: php, unlink

There is a file(644, owner:apache) that I can't delete it using a PHP script with unlink function.

I can't figure it out why unlink fails to delete this file.

BTW, I have tried fclose it before unlink it. Unfortunately, it still didn't work.

“drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache” apache have write access to the directory.

Comment: `<?php echo getmyuid() . ' - ' . getmygid(); ?>` what is the output ? I am guessing youre running your httpd server with antoher user that does not have access to the file.

Comment: it returns 500 - 500

Comment: 500 - 500, it's weird. Do you know what it suppose to mean?

Comment: that is sort of weird because considering the chmod 644 which allows others to erase the file it should work fine even from the httpd server, can you update with the unlink error ? 500 is the user id and group you can type `cat /etc/passwd |grep 500` on the console to check what username is it.

Comment: I am using the unlink function in PHP. According to the official document. This function "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure". So I don't know the specific error, is there a way to find it out?

Comment: “drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache” apache have write access to the directory.

Comment: When you find the solution by yourself (as I think it is a problem due to either your code, or something you didn't tell us), please update your question to tell the answer, even if it may make you look like a bit dumb :-)

Answer (score 2):

Does apache have write access to the directory that the file is in ?

Answer (score 0):

What server operating system are you using? It's possibly SELinux causing this - if you have an OS with that installed, look in /var/log/secure or maybe /var/log/audit/audit.log for mentions of the file you are trying to unlink.

Comment: I'm using Cent OS, and SELinux status is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys. Problem solved.

It turns out the other mistake in my script have caused the problem. But I still learned a lot in this discussion. Thanks.